# How to do REORG command on DB2

Tags: unix, db2

I want to reorganize(offline) some db2 tables.
Also I want to executing runstats command after reorg command.

I have a question.

Do I need to stop db2 database or deactivate or both of them before executing reorg command?

Answer (score 0):

No, the database must be available in order to connect to it and issue the `REORG` statement(s).  For an offline reorg, you may to avoid having other applications connected as an offline reorg will lock the table.